# Validar um número inteiro no Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Estou estudando a linguagem Python 3 e estou acompanhando um curso online, onde o professor passa o seguinte desafio:
"Faça um programa que jogue PAR ou ÍMPAR com o computador. O jogo será interrompido quando o jogador PERDER, mostrando o total de vitórias consecutivas que ele conquistou no final do jogo."
E, embora eu não seja ainda um programador, consegui desenvolver o programa. Porém, resolvi tentar incrementar com uma validação para os números que seriam digitados pelo usuário, no caso deste digitar uma string ou um símbolo, por exemplo, o laço retornaria de forma parecida como eu fiz para a opção da string (de P para par e I para ímpar). **Devo ressaltar que não quero limitar o usuário quanto à numeração a ser digitada, da forma que limitei o *randint*.**
Acredito que seja um problema realmente fácil de resolver para qualquer programador já iniciado, mas, mesmo na resolução, o professor faz apenas uma validação da string e não do número.
Abaixo, segue o código comentado com aspas triplas e também com cerquilha, para melhor entendimento da minha questão:

```
from random import randint

cont = 0
while True:
    comp = randint(0, 99)
    palpite = str(input('PAR ou ÍMPAR [P/I]? ')).strip().upper()
    while palpite not in 'PI': # Esta validação deu OK.
        print('Opção inválida. Digite P ou I.')
        palpite = str(input('PAR ou ÍMPAR [P/I]? ')).strip().upper()
    num = int(input('Escolha um número: '))
    '''
    while palpite == str:   #! Não consegui resolver <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        print('Opção inválida. Digite um número inteiro.')
        num = int(input('Escolha um número: '))
    '''
    res = (num + comp) % 2
    print(f'Eu escolhi {comp} e você escolheu {num}.')
    if res == 0 and palpite in 'P':
        cont += 1
        print(f'{num + comp} é PAR! Você GANHOU!')
    elif res != 0 and palpite in 'I':
        cont += 1
        print(f'{num + comp} é ÍMPAR! GANHOU!')
    elif res == 0 and palpite in 'I':
        print(f'{num + comp} é PAR! Você PERDEU!')
        print(f'Você ganhou {cont} vezes.')
        break
    elif res != 0 and palpite in 'P':
        print(f'{num + comp} ÍMPAR! Você PERDEU!')
        print(f'Você ganhou {cont} vezes.')
        break
print('>>>>> GAME OVER <<<<<')
```

Desde já, agradeço a atenção e colaboração!

Comment: Tente usar a função `isnumeric()`: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isnumeric.asp

Answer (score 1):

## Use:

[`try...except`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) com usando [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#int) aninhado:

```
while True:
  try:
    num = int(input('Escolha um número: '))
    break
  except ValueError:
    print("Não é um número!")

print(f'{num} é um número inteiro.')
```

Utilizando o método [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal):

```
while True:
  inp = input('Escolha um número: ')
  if inp.isdecimal(): break
  print("Não é um número inteiro decimal!")

num = int(inp)

print(f'{num} é um número inteiro decimal.')
```

## Não use:

Quando quiser converter uma string de entrada em inteiro decimal **não use** os métodos [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) ou [`str.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric).
A princípio pode parecer uma boa ideia utilizar esses métodos, mas quando estamos falando de Unicode todo cuidado é necessário.
Não adianta filtrar a entrada com o método `str.isascii()` antes de processar uma string com [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) ou [`str.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric), ambos os método são permissivos para elementos numéricos abrigados no bloco Unicode [Latin 1 Supplement](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BBlock%3DLatin%201%20Supplement%7D&esc=on&g=&i=) que não podem ser convertidos, sem tratamento especial, em inteiros decimais.

Segundo a documentação:

> `str.isdigit()`
> Retorna True se todos os caracteres na string são dígitos e existe pelo menos um caractere, False caso contrário.
> **Dígitos incluem caracteres decimais e dígitos que precisam de tratamento especial, tal como a compatibilidade com dígitos sobre-escritos.**
> Isso inclui **dígitos que não podem ser usados para formar números na base 10**, como por exemplo os números de *Kharosthi*.
> Formalmente, um dígito é um caractere que tem a propriedade com valor [`Numeric_Type=Digit`](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7Bnt%3Ddigit%7D&esc=on&g=&i=) ou [`Numeric_Type=Decimal`.](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7Bnt%3Ddecimal%7D&esc=on&g=&i=)

```
while True:
  inp = input('Escolha um número: ')
  if inp.isdigit(): break
  print("Não é um número inteiro decimal!")

num = int(inp)

print(f'{num} é um número inteiro decimal.')

Escolha um número: ²3455
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    num = int(inp)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '²3455'
```

> `str.isnumeric()`
> Retorna True se todos os caracteres na string são caracteres numéricos, e existe pelo menos um caractere, False caso contrário.
> Caracteres numéricos incluem dígitos, e **todos os caracteres que tem a propriedade/valor numérica Unicode***, isto é: U+2155, um quinto de fração vulgar.
> Formalmente, caracteres numéricos são aqueles que possuem propriedades com valor [`Numeric_Type=Digit`](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7Bnt%3Ddigit%7D&esc=on&g=&i=), [`Numeric_Type=Decimal`](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7Bnt%3Ddecimal%7D&esc=on&g=&i=) ou [`Numeric_Type=Numeric`](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7Bnt%3Dnumeric%7D&esc=on&g=&i=).

```
while True:
  inp = input('Escolha um número: ')
  if inp.isnumeric(): break
  print("Não é um número inteiro decimal!")

num = int(inp)

print(f'{num} é um número inteiro decimal.')

Escolha um número: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    num = int(inp)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Augusto!
Me ajudou muito! E eu realmente não queria usar o método de conversão.
A resposta ficou bem esclarecida. Valeu mesmo!